# Stop content shifting under vertical nav

Tags: html, css

I tried to fix this myself, it worked to an extent.

I used a combo of min and max widths, overflow:hidden and the display:inline-block. It stops shrinking, but it shifts the content under the navigation. I tried setting margins and an empty space holder, but no dice.

Basically the code works fine as it is. When shrinking the window, it shifts the content under the navigation bar.

[Here's the fiddle for the code](https://jsfiddle.net/mznnd8z0/)

HTML -

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>  
            fghgfhnjgfhgnfhhfggh
        </header>

        <nav>
            <div id="logo"> 
                <img  src="Images/Logo.png" >
            </div>                  

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
                    </a>                      
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            UI Components
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Pages
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="small-box">
            </div>

            <div class="small-box">
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer> 
            rueregrewghe
        </footer>
    </div>          
</body>
```

css -

```
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);

html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: rgb(110, 110, 110);
padding:0;
margin:0;
min-width:1079px;
overflow:hidden;

}
.container{
        margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

background: rgb(110, 110, 110);
width: 100%;
min-width:1079px;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}
header{
position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   width:calc(100% - 60px);
   min-width:1270px;
   height:108px; 
   background:rgb(57, 57, 57);

}
nav {
background:rgb(255, 90, 9);
position:fixed;
top:0;
height:calc(100% - 50px);
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .1s ease;
 transition-property:width .1s ease;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
float:left;
z-index:100;
 margin-right:140px;
}

nav:hover{
width:200px;
 transition-property:width .1s ease;

}
nav li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}
nav li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#efefef;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
margin-top:110px;
}
nav .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}
nav .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'times new roman', sans-serif;
}
nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
footer{
position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:50px; 
   background:rgb(57, 57, 57);
    min-width:1079px;
}
.content{
color:black;
float:right;
margin-top:108px;
top:0;
height:calc(100% - 158px);
position:absolute;
width:50%;
min-width:1150px;
margin-left:calc((100% - 1200px) /2);
padding:10px;

background-color:green;
overflow:hidden;
}
.small-box{
    float:left;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:435px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;

}
```

Comment: Hey, I expanded it, thanks for the feedback. If you could take a look at it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Question is still unclear, sorry. What exactly, in specific terms, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, the only change I notice is the second menu item is no longer visible when you begin to constrain the page width... perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to make a responsive layout? or are you trying to create a structured layout with a sort of grid /table ?

Comment: I was trying to make it a bit hybrid, a mixture of liquid and fixed positioning, the containers shifting position but the actual content boxes being fixed in place, but I had encountered an issue in which if you minimized the window of the webpage too much, it would slide one of the yellow content boxes under the navigation, taking up around half of it and when you expanded the nav, it would completely cover the content box. I was wondering if you knew how to fix it. I managed to find a work around, but I am still curious as to how you'd fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are using display: table-cell but you have no tables or table rows defined. this may help: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393925/how-do-we-use-displaytable-cell)

Secondly you are mixing floats as well as position absolute/relative. A relative element positions itself and adjusts its position according to a certain element. In this case its positions based on the position of the header. The content is absolutely positioned so it doesn't adjust like the navigation.

Comment: About the display: table-cell I was using a work around that was suggested. I removed it and it had no effect, but thanks for the link it was interesting. What helped me was your advice about the positioning, I changed it to relative, which helped with the issue I was facing. Adding padding took care of the issue of the text being covered. So yeah, the positioning was the issue for anyone else who has a similar issue.